# Find the probability in poisson distribution python

Tags: python, scipy, poisson

Qeustion:
Expected number of accident at a junction is 5 per month. then What is the probability of more than 7 accidents at the junction next month? You can use python scipy library for this. Even though I can do this on a paper, its little difficult to do by coding with these library. Can you help me

the method is

```
import scipy.stats as stats
find_prob(a,b):
#input: probability of event interval
#output: determined probability
```

Comment: I can't see how your question is somehow related to a poisson distribution. Am I missing something?

Comment: no thats all. It can be measure using the formula of poission distribution  by finding probability from 0-7 and reduce them from 1. But i have to use the scipy library

Comment: Well, then you should look at the documentation of the [poisson distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html) within the scipy package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you are only wanted to find the probability larger than seven right?

If yes, I think this is one of the approach to do so ask follow:

```
    from scipy import stats

    occur_past = 5
    ask_current = 7

    mu = occur_past
    x = ask_current

    upto7 = scipy.stats.poisson.pmf(x, mu)
    above7 = 1 - upto7
```

The output would be 0.8955551370429461

You can simply convert into function as follow:

```
   def poisson(mu, x):

         uptocurrent = scipy.stats.poisson.pmf(x, mu)
         abovecurrent = 1 - uptocurrent
         return abovecurrent
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there is no need to create a new function. You just need to define the random variable before:

```py
from scipy import stats

X=stats.poisson(5)

print(1-X.cdf(7)) #Note that X.cdf(7)=P(X<=7)
```

Output:

```
0.1333716740700075
```